# Can you please verify if I solved correctly?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

The height of the object that was dropped is given by $S(t)=-16t^2+50$
What is the average velocity of this object between t=1 and t=1.5?

Average speed given by (f(b)-f(a))/b-a
which gives me following:
(f(1.5)-f(1))/0.5 which equals -40?

Comment: Yeah, I would also calculate it like this. Looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you! Calculus makes me feel stupid =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this question just seems like joining two points and find the slope of the line.
so you are correct

Comment: no need to use calculus at all

Comment: Never thought of it this way! Wow! It makes sense now!